# Help tranlating sentence with mo

Tags: particles, english-to-japanese

Given

そこではなにもかもが曖昧になる

I have

Soko de wa nani mo kamo ga aimai ni nare.

What does this mean?  The mo is hard to understand.  I think its something like

"Here we may be a sitting duck."

Comment: 何もかも is basically it's own word, which means something like 'absolutely everything'. Does that help?
(also, it's 'aimai ni naru' at the end)

Comment: You should get in a habit of reading Japanese the way it's written instead of romanizing it before you try to understand it.

Comment: @snailboat - Thanks.  I'm trying for sure, however with my limited vocabulary I make mistakes such as this where I think I'm dealing with 3 words and there's only 1.  The romaji helps clarify my thought process when I ask questions (namely word seperation).

Comment: @Sjiveru - Yes very helpful!  So I think the sentence means "Absolutely everything here is headed into ambiguity."  FWIW, I'm translating a Manga into english.

Comment: Yeah, or something like 'that's a place where absolutely everything becomes ambiguous'.
(also, what manga?)

Comment: @Sjiveru Full Metal Panic - burning one man force (small novel 8).  Also if you post your first comment as the answer I will mark it.  That answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

何もかも is basically a word on its own. It means something along the lines of 'absolutely everything' - it's in effect an intensified version of 何も. Adding that in, the whole sentence becomes something like 'that's a place where absolutely everything becomes ambiguous'. (Though you might want to be careful translating 曖昧, as 'ambiguous' isn't always the best translation for it.)